# Reference to elements adds (unwanted) namespace to target xml

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, element, ref

my overall goal is to break down a big xsd in several small xsd's, one especially holding elements and complex types I want to reuse in the other xsds. Say the type xsd is called "types.xsd" and the one of the other xsds is called "request.xsd"

That being said, I declared one central ID "evalancheId" as an element and try to reference (using ref) to them. However, the resulting XML comes with an unwanted namespace prefix "ns:evalancheId" for the referenced elemeent.

**types.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://hansgrohe.com/pi/PA/C4C/Contact/10" 
xmlns="http://hansgrohe.com/pi/PA/C4C/Contact/10">

<xsd:element name="evalancheId" type="xsd:int"/>

<xsd:complexType name="contactComplexType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="givenName">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                    <xsd:maxLength value="40"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <!-- ... -->
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**request.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://hansgrohe.com/pi/PA/C4C/Contact/10" 
xmlns="http://hansgrohe.com/pi/PA/C4C/Contact/10">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="types.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name="updateContactReq" type="contactUpgradeComplexType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="contactUpgradeComplexType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="contactComplexType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="evalancheId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**result.xml**

```
<ns:updateContactReq xmlns:ns="http://hansgrohe.com/pi/PA/C4C/Contact/10">
    <givenName>Jay</givenName>
    <ns:evalancheId>0815</ns:evalancheId>
</ns:updateContactReq>
```

**actually_wanted.xml**

```
<ns:updateContactReq xmlns:ns="http://hansgrohe.com/pi/PA/C4C/Contact/10">
    <givenName>Jay</givenName>
    <evalancheId>0815</evalancheId>
</ns:updateContactReq>
```

**Question**

1. How can I get rid of the namespace in "ns:evalancheId" and yet reuse the evalancheId element

Many thanks and kind regards
Tschenser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can. Only global elements are visible for reuse by the including/importing XSD. But global elements are always in the target namespace of their own XSD. 
You could set elementFormDefault to 'unqualified' and declare the element as a local (i.e. non-global) element definition. But that would defeat your objective of having the element contained in a separate XSD.
I think the best solution for you would be to define the *types* in a separate XSD but the *element declarations* locally in your main XSD. That way, the element declaration can be local, while the complex type is defined in a separate XSD.